# Slice vectors inside a map

Tags: c++, boost

I have a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`. Is there a way to provide a "view" of that map to a function that takes a variable of the same type? Specifically, is there a way to slice the vectors within the map, yet provide a view (sliced) that is compliant to the std::map interface? Something similar to `boost` range adapters or indexes, but for nested structures.

I am mainly looking for something via `boost`, but I am open to other suggestions as well.

[UPDATE] the goal is to "NOT" copy or move the map, only access its vectors according to the slicing criteria. And the function that takes the map as a variable should not be aware of the slicing. I hope this makes the question clearer.

Here's a pseudo example:

```
map<string, vector<int>> my_map; 
my_map["a"] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
my_map["b"] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
my_map["c"] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

map<string, pair<int>> slices;
slices["a"] = {1,4};
slices["b"] = {2,3};
slices["c"] = {0,5};

map_view = magic(my_map, slices);

cout << "a: " << print_vector(map_view["a"]) << endl;
cout << "b: " << print_vector(map_view["b"]) << endl;
cout << "c: " << print_vector(map_view["c"]) << endl;

//desired output

a: 1,2,3
b: 2
c: 0,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: why the down vote? What is not clear about the question?

Comment: you might like boost::interval_set - but as given, your samples don't show what you want this for so I won't advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a function that takes one of the map values and a slicing criteria, then returns a joined boost range over multiple boost slices, depending on the slicing criteria. In addition to that, I resorted to using `auto` return type inference of C++14 to avoid messing with the actual return types of boost adaptors and ranges.

Here's a quick snippet:

```
const auto get_map_view(
    string key, 
    const map<string, vector<int>> & my_map, 
    const pair<int,int> & slice, bool exclude=false) {

    const auto & values = my_map.at(key);

    if (!exclude) {
        return boost::range::join(
            values | boost::adaptors::sliced(0, 0),
            values | boost::adaptors::sliced(slice.first, slice.second));
    } else {
        return boost::range::join(
            values | boost::adaptors::sliced(0, slice.first),
            values | boost::adaptors::sliced(slice.second, values.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No magic needed try this:

```
auto& ref_map = my_map["a"];
auto& ref_slice = slices["a"];
std::cout << "a: ";
std::copy ( 
    ref_map.begin() + ref_slice.first,
    ref_map.begin() + ref_slice.second,
    std::ostream_iterator<int> (std::cout,", ") 
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
( auto a)[&]{ auto bounds = slices[a];
              auto v = mymap[a];
              return find(v.begin(),v.end(), bounds.first);}
```

This for example will get you an iterator to the front edge based on your criterion the rest should be trivial with lambdas.